# Parallel execution doesn't update my variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I want to write a program where, random numbers are going to be created and I am going to track down the greatest of them. Two threads are going to run in parallel. However, my `best` variable is stuck at its initial variable. Why?

[EDIT]

I updated the code after Joachim's answer, but I am not getting the correct answer at every run! What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex
#include <random>

std::default_random_engine generator((unsigned int)time(0));
int random(int n) {
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, n);
  return distribution(generator);
}

std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section

void update_cur_best(int& cur_best, int a, int b) {
  // critical section (exclusive access to std::cout signaled by locking mtx):
  mtx.lock();
  if(a > b)
        cur_best = a;
  else
        cur_best = b;
  mtx.unlock();
}

 void run(int max, int& best) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
                int a = random(max); int b = random(max);
                update_cur_best(best, a, b);
                mtx.lock();
                std::cout << "|" << a << "| |" << b << "|" << std::endl;
                mtx.unlock();
        }
}

int main ()
{
  int best = 0;
  std::thread th1 (run, 100, std::ref(best));
  std::thread th2 (run, 100, std::ref(best));

  th1.join();
  th2.join();

  std::cout << "best = " << best << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
|4| |21|
|80| |75|
|93| |95|
|4| |28|
|52| |92|
|96| |12|
|83| |8|
|4| |33|
|28| |35|
|59| |52|
|20| |73|
|60| |96|
|61| |34|
|67| |79|
|67| |95|
|54| |57|
|20| |75|
|40| |30|
|16| |32|
|25| |100|
|33| |36|
|69| |26|
|94| |46|
|15| |57|
|50| |68|
|9| |56|
|46| |70|
|65| |65|
|76| |73|
|16| |29|
best = 29
```

I am getting 29, which is not the maximum!

Comment: By the way, why aren't you simply using e.g. `best = std::max(a, b);`?

Comment: You're overwriting the value of `best` *every time* you call `update_cur_best`, so at the end it's simply the greater of the last `a`, `b` pair generated.

Comment: @JohannesD And I think that's the answer you should write.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah, done.

Comment: Now with the answer from JohannesD, you could use nested [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) call: `best = std::max(best, std::max(a, b))`

Comment: How did this get unmarked as duplicate?  The other question did exactly answer the question here, "my `best` variable is stuck at its initial [value]. Why?"

Comment: @BenVoigt Probably because the linked duplicate didn't address the *whole* problem, just one part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you can't really pass references to the thread constructor, because they will not be passed on as references, but copied and it's those copies that are passed to your thread function. You have to use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to wrap the reference.

E.g.

```
std::thread th1 (run, 100, std::ref(best));
```

Comment: Ehem, but thread accepts references as arguments. Their content being copied is another issue.

Comment: This helped, but I am not getting the correct value at every run! I am updating my question!

Answer (score 3):

As an answer to the updated question, in `update_cur_best` the value of `best` is overwritten on each iteration. In the end, its value will simply be the greater of the most recent `a`, `b` pair generated. What you want to do is update it only when the current `a` or `b` is greater than `best` (I'm not sure why you generate two random values on each iteration...)

Comment: Two values per iteration for no reason. Yes I found the bug with help of another answer, but I deleted the relevant question. I am going to accept the previous answer however, because it was first. :)